# c# crop image on specific pixel

Tags: c#, image, pointers

i would like to crop an image from a full image only at a specific part this is my code

```
    private unsafe Bitmap GetDiffBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
    {

        BitmapData bmDataRes;
        bmpRes = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

        bmData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);

        bmDataRes = bmpRes.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpRes.Width, bmpRes.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;

        IntPtr scan0Res = bmDataRes.Scan0;


        int stride = bmData.Stride;

        int strideRes = bmDataRes.Stride;

        int nWidth = bmp.Width;
        int nHeight = bmp.Height;

        for(int y = 0; y < nHeight; y++)

        {

            byte* p = (byte*)scan0.ToPointer();
            p += y * stride;

            byte* pRes = (byte*)scan0Res.ToPointer();
            pRes += y * strideRes;

            for (int x = 0; x < nWidth; x++)
            {
                //always get the complete pixel when differences are found
                if (p[0] ==255)
                {
                          pRes[0] = p[0];
                    pRes[1] = p[1];
                    pRes[2] = p[2];

                    //alpha (opacity)
                    pRes[3] = p[3];
                }

                else
                {



                    bmpRes.UnlockBits(bmDataRes);

                    break;


                }


                p += 4;

                pRes += 4;
            }

        }


        return bmpRes;


    }
```

as you can see i just want to copy the pixels when the red byte is 255 and if its not,immediently to stop and break. i want to find continuous red parts.
but im getting a weird exception on that line  when i release the bitmap 
`bmpRes.UnlockBits(bmDataRes);` the exception -**`A generic error occurred in GDI+`** any idea why is it throwing that error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should break the outter `for` loop as well.

What happens is that you're trying to UnlockBits more than once, actually.

Or more simply you can change

```
bmpRes.UnlockBits(bmDataRes);
break;
```

into

```
bmpRes.UnlockBits(bmDataRes);
return bmpRes;
```

Comment: you would normally use a `bool` and call it `doneWithBmpData` or something, and check in the outter loop if you need to break it as well. But a simpler solution can be found in my answer.